# iOS - How to place chosen images onto the appropriate image view (imagePickerController)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.  I have a custom Table View Cell (called MyCustomCell) in which there is an image view and a button that, when clicked, opens the camera. The user can add more of these cells.  I want the user to be able to click on a button, take a picture, and have that appear in the appropriate image view for that button.

My issue is that right now it is always appearing in the first image view but not the others.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage : UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {   
        let scancell = tableView.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath) as! MyCustomCell // it's this line that is wrong
        scancell.imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        scancell.imgView.image = pickedImage
        scancell.cameraButton.isHidden = true
    };

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I'm having hard time understanding how the imagePickerController gets called and if I can pass in the custom cell that the user clicked on.

I want to do something like this:

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: tableView.indexPath(for: cell))
```

where `cell` is passed into the argument somehow but I'm not sure if the signature of the `imagePickerController` can be modified and if so, how exactly is it called?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a tag to the button in cellForRow method and use that tag to get the cell.

```
var Celltag = 0

    func tableView_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell((withIdentifier: "")) as! MyCustomCell
    cell.customButton.tag =  indexPath.row
    cell.customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonClickMethod), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
    }


    func ButtonClickMethod (sender:UIButton) {
    Celltag = sender.tag
    ........
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage : UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {   
            let scancell = tableView.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: Celltag, section: 0) as IndexPath) as! MyCustomCell 
            scancell.imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            scancell.imgView.image = pickedImage
            scancell.cameraButton.isHidden = true
        };

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't do it quite like this but this answer helped me get on the right track.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your MyCustomCell class you should have this function for imagePicker where the user can select one photo and return the photo your user chose.Then, in the tableViewController data source method with cellForRow (where you also pass the indexPath of the cell your user clicked on) you should have something like

```
 func tableView_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(...) as! MyCustomCell
     let image = cell.pickImage
     cell.image = image

     return cell 
 }
```